# Rails Foreman Start Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

Trying to run my app locally using foreman (ruby 1.9.3 rails 4) using: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

I get the following error, has anyone got any advice to resolve this - thanks in advance everyone:

```
C:\Sites\joshuapp>foreman start
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dotenv-0.10.0/lib/dotenv/en
vironment.rb:53:in `block in load': Line "\"RACK_ENV=development\" " doesn't mat
ch format (Dotenv::FormatError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dotenv-0.10.0/
lib/dotenv/environment.rb:33:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dotenv-0.10.0/
lib/dotenv/environment.rb:33:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dotenv-0.10.0/
lib/dotenv/environment.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:172:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0
/lib/foreman/engine.rb:172:in `load_env'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0
/lib/foreman/cli.rb:136:in `load_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0
/lib/foreman/cli.rb:38:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.63.0
/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/foreman:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/foreman:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show your .env file?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have unnecessary quotes around the `RACK_ENV=development` string

Comment: These quotes are created by the commands: $ echo "RACK_ENV=development" >> .env $ echo "PORT=3000" >> .env - Do they need to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have the wrong version of dotenv. I just ran into the same issue right now. I debugged my version of dotenv like this:

```
➜ gem list | grep dotenv
```

The latest version seems to be 0.11.1 as of this writing, so that's what gets automatically installed.  To get around this, simply add the version of dotenv you need in your Gemfile and then type "bundle install"

```
  gem 'dotenv', '~> 0.1.0'
```

voila... foreman starts.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check the format of your .env file. It is possibly in a wrong format, note the `Dotenv::FormatError` in the logs.